# Pandas extract multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using Pandas I am adding new columns to a DataFrame:

```
df["Year"] = df["concat"].str.extract("(\d\d\d\d$)", expand=False)
df["Month"] = df["concat"].str.extract("(\d\d)\_\d\d\d\d$", expand=False)
df["Measure"] = df["concat"].str.extract("^(.*)\_\d\d\_\d\d\d\d$", expand=False)
```

This works but is very slow. I was thinking about doing all 3 operations in one step (hoping that would increase performance):

```
df["Measure", "Year", "Month"] = (df["concat"].str.extract("^(?P<Measure>.*)\_(?P<Month>\d\d)\_(?P<Year>\d\d\d\d)$", expand=True))
```

But that does not work (ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1).

How to make it work or how effectively extract this information?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in 3 separate values into your df reference as `df["Measure", "Year", "Month"]`. `"Measure"`, `"Year"` and `"Month"` instead of a single array `["Measure","Year","Month"]`. It should look like `df[["Measure", "Year", "Month"]]` instead.

Alternatively, you can use pandas concatenate function.

```
df2= df["concat"].str.extract("^(?P<Measure>.*)\_(?P<Month>\d\d)\_(?P<Year>\d\d\d\d)$", expand=True)
pd.concat([df,df2],axis = 1)
```